# airflow user impersonation (run_as_user) not working

Tags: airflow

I am trying to use run_as_user feature in airflow for our DAG and we are facing some issues. Any help or recommendations?

```
DAG Code:from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.bash_operator import BashOperator
current_time = datetime.now() - timedelta(days=1)
default_args = {
    'start_date': datetime.strptime(current_time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'),'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'),
    'run_as_user': 'airflowaduser',
    'execution_timeout': timedelta(minutes=5)
}
dag = DAG('test_run-as_user', default_args=default_args,description='Run hive Query DAG', schedule_interval='0 * * * *',)
hive_ex = BashOperator(
    task_id='hive-ex',
    bash_command='whoami',
    dag=dag
)
```

i have airflow added to sudoers and it can switch to airflowaduser without password from Linux shell.

`airflow ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL`

Error details below while running the DAG:

```
*** Reading local file: /home/airflow/logs/test_run-as_user/hive-ex/2020-06-09T16:00:00+00:00/1.log
[2020-06-09 17:00:04,602] {taskinstance.py:620} INFO - Dependencies all met for <TaskInstance: test_run-as_user.hive-ex 2020-06-09T16:00:00+00:00 [queued]>
[2020-06-09 17:00:04,613] {taskinstance.py:620} INFO - Dependencies all met for <TaskInstance: test_run-as_user.hive-ex 2020-06-09T16:00:00+00:00 [queued]>
[2020-06-09 17:00:04,613] {taskinstance.py:838} INFO - 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[2020-06-09 17:00:04,613] {taskinstance.py:839} INFO - Starting attempt 1 of 1
[2020-06-09 17:00:04,613] {taskinstance.py:840} INFO - 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[2020-06-09 17:00:04,651] {taskinstance.py:859} INFO - Executing <Task(BashOperator): hive-ex> on 2020-06-09T16:00:00+00:00
[2020-06-09 17:00:04,651] {base_task_runner.py:133} INFO - Running: ['sudo', '-E', '-H', '-u', 'airflowaduser', 'airflow', 'run', 'test_run-as_user', 'hive-ex', '2020-06-09T16:00:00+00:00', '--job_id', '2314', '--pool', 'default_pool', '--raw', '-sd', 'DAGS_FOLDER/test_run-as_user/testscript.py', '--cfg_path', '/tmp/tmpbinlgw54']
[2020-06-09 17:00:04,664] {base_task_runner.py:115} INFO - Job 2314: Subtask hive-ex sudo: airflow: command not found
[2020-06-09 17:00:09,576] {logging_mixin.py:95} INFO - [[34m2020-06-09 17:00:09,575[0m] {[34mlocal_task_job.py:[0m105} INFO[0m - Task exited with return code 1[0m
```

And our airflow runs in virtual environment.

Answer (score 1):

When running airflow in a virtual environment, only the user 'airflow' is configured to run `airflow` commands. If you want to run as another user, you need to set the home directory to be the same as for the airflow user (`/home/airflow`) and have it belong to the `0` group. See [https://airflow.apache.org/docs/docker-stack/entrypoint.html#allowing-arbitrary-user-to-run-the-container]

Additionally, the `run_as_user` feature calls `sudo`, which is only allowed to use the secure path. The location of the `airflow` commands is not part of the secure path, but it can be added in the sudoers file. You can use `whereis airflow` to check where the airflow directory is, in my container it was `/home/airflow/.local/bin`

To solve this I needed to add 4 lines to my Dockerfile:

```
RUN useradd -u [airflowaduser UID] -g 0 -d /home/airflow kettle && \
  # create airflowaduser
  usermod -u [airflow UID] -aG sudo airflow && \
  # add airflow to sudo group
  echo "airflow ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL" >> /etc/sudoers && \
  # allow airflow to run sudo without a password
  sed -i 's#/.venv/bin#/home/airflow/.local/bin:/.venv/bin#' /etc/sudoers
  # update secure path to include the airflow directory
```